# Windows 7: After wake from sleep, Maximum CPU P-State always sets to 5%

Tags: windows-7, sleep, power-management

Ok, I've been tracing an issue my box is having with Sleep (S3) and the maximum P-State set in the Active Power Plan after waking. After my machine wakes, the maximum P-State of the Active Power Plan is always set to 5%. This happens no matter the Power Plan used: Balanced, High Performance, or the custom one the OEM tuning software installs. It happens even when the OEM software is disabled and I'm just using the default power plans. It happens even after the Power Plans have been reset to defaults, with no changes. The machine sleeps fine, wakes fine. After it wakes though, I have to go in and reset the maximum P-State back to 100% if I want it to run at the appropriate speed.

I've done a whole lot of googling and I've only found a couple other sites where behavior like this has been described. In all those cases, I've found no resolution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After much gnashing of teeth, I've come up with an ugly fix for this problem. I still haven't identified the cause, however, I used the Windows 7 Task scheduler to run command line executions of "powercfg.exe" to set the maximum values for the process state back to 100 whenever the System Log receives an event from "Power-Troubleshooter" of #1, which is a system wake event. To set up that command, you need to run a few queries to get GUIDs for your Power Plan and then for the subgroup and specific index for the controls in question. I suggest the following format for those commands, because the listing is more than the command console can display.

First run:

```
powercfg -l > <yourdesktoppath>\list.txt
```

This will list all the power plans with their respective GUIDs

Next with the plan you want to fix run:

```
powercfg -q <yourplanGUID> > <yourdesktoppath>\plan.txt
```

Next comb that plan.txt file for a subgroup called "Processor power management". Make node of that GUID. Right below it you will see GUIDs for the min and max processor states as well. Note those.

Next run Scheduled Tasks, to setup your correction task. Set a trigger and change the pulldown to "event" then specify the System log and manually enter "Power-Troubleshooter" into the source and "1" into the event.

For the Action of your event, Run the program: "powercfg.exe" found in System32, and add the argument as follows.

```
-setacvalueindex <powerplanGUID> <processpowermanagerGUID> <specificsettingGUID> 100.
```

Create a task for each setting you want to fix. My tests show this is restoring the power P-State on wake.